# NodeJS: JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, nestjs, heap-memory

In my Node.js application, there's a function that causes the application to crash with the error: `Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`. I suspect this could be related to executing a large number of asynchronous operations simultaneously, which may lead to memory exhaustion.

However, I'm not sure how to fix it. Perhaps someone has some ideas?

```
async updateLinks() {
  const medias = await this.mediaModel.find()
  this.logger.log('Cron Job: Updating Urls .....')
  for(let media of medias) {
    const url = await this.testService.getPreSignedUrl(media.key)
    media.url = url
    media.save()
  }
  this.logger.log('Cron Job: Completed ')
}
```

```
async getPreSignedUrl(key: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const data = await this.s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Key: key,
      Bucket: process.env.BUCKET_ID,
      Expires: 600000 // almost a week
    });
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    this.logger.error(err);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you use the Redis cron job? if it is you should check the job completed in memory, it's take too much memory, you can delete it when completed.

Comment: maybe you will extend your memory limit by run command `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`

Comment: @HaiAlison I'm using the nestjs framework, with nestjs/schedule. And this function is called using the decorator @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_WEEK)

Comment: There's no possibility to expand the memory due to server limitations. Even if it were possible, would it make sense? If there's more data, the application will still crash regardless of how much memory is available.

Comment: so i think your payload is too large to transfer something like this lead on the heap out of memory problem, try increasing max_old_space_size

Comment: Can you show us the code for `getPreSignedUrl()` and for `media.save()`?  It's possible that `await media.save()` would help, but that depends upon the code in `media.save()` so we can only know if we see that code.  Similarly, we need to make sure that `getPreSignedUrl()` is properly returning a promise that is tied to when that operation is complete.

Comment: @jfriend00 I added the `getPreSignedUrl()` function.
`media.save()` is a Mongodb function that saves data to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all your operations from running parallel, add an `await` in front of `media.save()` like this:

```
async updateLinks() {
  const medias = await this.mediaModel.find()
  this.logger.log('Cron Job: Updating Urls .....')
  for(let media of medias) {
    const url = await this.testService.getPreSignedUrl(media.key)
    media.url = url
    await media.save()
  }
  this.logger.log('Cron Job: Completed ')
}
```

Without that `await`, `updateLinks()` returns BEFORE the save is done and thus you get lots of `save()` operation in flight at the same time which could (if the `for` loop is large) overwhelm some sort of resource.  Instead, with the `await`, the operations will be sequenced one at a time.

If you were calling `updateLinks()` more than once or in a loop, you would also want an `await` on that call.